# Error en session_start() al tratar de inicializar la sesion

Tags: php, html, sesiones

Tengo el siguiente problema: Trabajando en usbwebserver funcionaba bien, sin embargo al subir el proyecto a 000webhost el session_start(); no funciona he colocado un "or die"para ver si era al leer la sesión o al crearla y es al crearla cuando ni siquiera puede iniciar la sesión creada.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        if(isset($_POST["username"]) &&isset($_POST["password"]))
        {
            if($_POST["username"]!=""&&$_POST["password"]!="")
            {
                include "conexion.php";
                if ($con->connect_errno) {
                    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " .$con->connect_error;
                }
                echo $con->host_info . "\n";
                
                $user_id=null;
                $sql1= "select * from usuarios where (usuario=\"$_POST[username]\" and password=\"$_POST[password]\")";
                $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die ("Error en $sql1: " . mysqli_error());
                $r=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $user_estado=$r["Estado"];
                $user_id=$r["id"];
                echo $user_id;
                mysqli_close($con);
                if($user_id==null)
                {
                    print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido AQUI SE MODIFICO.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    session_start() or die('Error iniciando gestor de variables de sesión');
                    $_SESSION["user_id"]=$user_id;
                    $_SESSION["user_estado"]=$user_estado;
                    print "<script>alert(\"Datos".$_SESSION["user_id"]." ".$_SESSION["user_estado"]."\")</script>";
                    print "<script>window.location='../home.php';</script>";                
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hasta donde recuerdo, `session_start()` es lo primerísimo primero que se hace. Tener una sesión asociada en el servidor no significa que quedes autenticado de una vez; sólo que preservas algunos datos en el servidor (en principio, nada más que la ID de usuario). Y según recuerdo, si hay alguna salida (un print, echo o similar) antes de session_start, hay líos.

Comment: Sesion start() siempre debe ir de primero para despues usar las variables de sesion, dejanos ver que error obtienes ?, no tenemos informacion suficiente para darte una posible solucion. Deberias mostrar el codigo que envia las cosas a travez del metodo POST

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se trata de un error típico, resulta que `session_start()` siempre debe de estar en la cabecera de tu documento de php.

Te debería de quedar algo así:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) &&isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        if($_POST["username"]!=""&&$_POST["password"]!="")
        {
            include "conexion.php";
            if ($con->connect_errno) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " .$con->connect_error;
            }
            echo $con->host_info . "\n";
            
            $user_id=null;
            $sql1= "select * from usuarios where (usuario=\"$_POST[username]\" and password=\"$_POST[password]\")";
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die ("Error en $sql1: " . mysqli_error());
            $r=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $user_estado=$r["Estado"];
            $user_id=$r["id"];
            echo $user_id;
            mysqli_close($con);
            if($user_id==null)
            {
                print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido AQUI SE MODIFICO.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION["user_id"]=$user_id;
                $_SESSION["user_estado"]=$user_estado;
                print "<script>alert(\"Datos".$_SESSION["user_id"]." ".$_SESSION["user_estado"]."\")</script>";
                print "<script>window.location='../home.php';</script>";                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>